# Azure releases: app service deployment in wrong resources

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I've two app service in the same resource group: a web app and a function app.
I'm experimenting a very weird behaviour of App Service deployment task.

If I disable one task I see the same code deployed in both services. If I enable both I see the same code of the last deplyoed in both services.

I'm absolutely sure that tasks reference the correct artifact and I get same unexpected results also using directly `az deployment source config-zip`.

Sometime I see the same behaviour also deploying directly from Visual Studio. This is not easily reproducible since sometime works correctly and sometimes not.

I doubt that can be of any help, but these are the release tasks:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: webapp'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'XXX-QTA'
    WebAppName: 'bvdof-webapp-eu-qta'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/SourceQTA/drop/a/BV.DigitalOrderForm.Web.zip'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: funcapp'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'XXX-QTA'
    appType: functionApp
    WebAppName: 'bvdof-funcapp-eu-qta'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/SourceQTA/drop/a/BV.DigitalOrderForm.Import.AzFunction.zip'
  enabled: false
```

I tried to move the second publish task to another stage without having different outcomes. I tried to define a specific build and release and the problem got not fixed.

I think that what is really happening is that the publish or the function app is performed in the web app resource.

I'd really appreciate any possibile solution or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

All this weirdness was my fault :(

Investigating and trying and retrying I noticed same files in both App Services file system.

Looking at the storage account (shared by both) confirmed this.

I had an error in the Bicep provisioning file, setting WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE with the same value!

Changed the value fixed the issue: each service must reside in its own share.